# Question about the deep web

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, security, website

I have been researching about Tor and the deep web and I wish to connect to the deep web. I have a task that I need to find someone for and I have been told the only way it is possible is to ask someone on the deep web. Now what I want to ask is whether the deep web is safe for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Tor, or conecting to the Tor network, does not bring any danger in and of itself.

Tor is just a tool. (You've been researching so you know what it does and how.) If you know exactly where to go, then using Tor to go there is not unsafe. Not less safe than it would be if Tor weren't required anyway.

That said, and regardless of Tor or whatever other tools, it is *impossible* to do anything online without leaving traces, and it is *very difficult* to avoid those traces pointing back to you. (Especially when paying money is involved.)
**Tor can help you there, but Tor is not a magic cloak.**
In order to be safe, you have to understand all possible threats, which measures you can take to avoid those threats, and understand how and why said measures work and when/why they would not work.

If you don't know exactly where to go and what to do, but have to *find* it, beware of hijacking, cloning, MITM-ing, etc.. that goes on with anything 'for profit'.

If you plan to undertake something where it would pose danger to you when someone else finds out what you did or that it was you who did it, it depends on how big the danger is and who this someone else is. If the danger is prison and the adversary is a powerful government organization, then no, it is not safe for you to do. Not because the deep web is unsafe, but because security is hard.